# How to retrieve questions for online examination SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

First of all I scheduled an exam for a particular module. module contains more then 2-3 chapters, each chapter contains more then 50-60 questions of different marks. Now problem is here to retrieve question from all the chapters and should be exactly same no of question and sum of marks should be same as saved at exam scheduled time.

```
table [Module](    
[module_id]
[module_name]
)

table [Chapter](        
[chapter_id]        
[module_id]        
[chapter_name]       
)

question_bank table          
[question_id]  [chapter_name]  [question_text]  [Marks]       
10001          .NET            Question1         1                                
10002          .NET            Question2         2                  
10003          .NET            Question3         4 
10004          .NET            Question4         1                                
10005          .NET            Question5         1                  
10006          .NET            Question6         4   
10007          .NET            Question7         1             
10008          .NET            Question8         2
10009          .NET            Question9         1

exam_schedule table                  
[exam_id]    [module_id]   [question]   [total_marks]          
1001          1001           6            10   

Output should be something like : 
[question_id] [exam_id]   [question_text]  [Marks]       
10001             1001        Question1         1                                
10002             1001        Question2         2                  
10004             1001        Question4         1                                
10005             1001        Question5         1                  
10006             1001        Question6         4  
10009             1001        Question9         1
```

Comment: Please provide desired output.

Comment: I provided the desired output

Comment: It seems you want to generate, randomly, a set of of questions for an scheduled exam, having the number of questions and total_marks specified during exam scheduling. Isn't it? If so, it'd be better to do that on the application side (ASP.Net) and not on the SQL-Server side.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
select qb.question_id, es.exam_id, qb.question_text, sum(qb.marks) Marks
from question_bank qb
inner join Chapter c on c.chapter_name = qb.chapter_name
inner join Module m on m.module_id = c.module_id
inner join exam_schedule es on es.module_id = m.module_id
group by qb.question_id, es.exam_id, qb.question_text
```

Or, if `[question]` in exam_schedule maps to `question_id`:

```
select qb.question_id, exam_id, question_text, total_marks Marks
from exam_schedule es
inner join question_bank qb on qb.question_id = exam_schedule.question
```